# How to use a dictionary to translate a start and end date to a period of time, eg jan-dec being a calender year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has the start date and end date of a period of time as `yyyy-mm` and I want to have a new column which has the period of time - for example start date of `2019-01` and end date of `2019-12` would be `Cal-19` in the new column, want to have this for years and quarters and then if it isn't either of those to do `mm-yyyy - mm-yyyy` as a string of the start to end dates.

I have tried to do this with a dictionary which had two inputs, start and end date, and would have the output for the period but this hasn't worked.

```
from Dictionary import Period

df["Start Period"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period("M")

df["End Period"]=pd.to_datetime(df["End Date"], dayfirst=True).dt.to_period("M")

df["Period"] = df["Start Period"].map(Period) #This is the line which isn't working
```

Where Period is a dictionary as follows:

```
Period = dict({("2019-01","2019-12"):"Cal-19",
            ("2020-01","2020-12"):"Cal-20",
            ("2021-01","2021-12"):"Cal-21",
            ("2019-01","2019-03"):"Q1-19",
            ("2019-04","2019-06"):"Q2-19",
            ("2019-07","2019-09"):"Q3-19",
            ("2019-10","2019-12"):"Q4-19",
            ("2020-01","2020-03"):"Q1-20",
            ("2020-04","2020-06"):"Q2-20",
            ("2020-07","2020-09"):"Q3-20"})
```

Would expect to get the period but get an error within the dictionary itself but even when trying on a small subset of data I get `NaN` in the output column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that the date in `Start Date` and `End Date` is in string format. Otherwise the code below needs adjustment.
This should do the trick:

```
def get_period_form_start_and_end(x):
    yr_start = x['Start Date'][0:4]
    yr_end = x['End Date'][0:4]
    m_start = x['Start Date'][5:7]
    m_end = x['End Date'][5:7]

    if yr_start == yr_end:
        if m_start == "01" and m_end == "12":
            return "Cal-" + yr_start[2:4]
        elif m_start == "01" and m_end == "03":
            return "Q1-" + yr_start[2:4]
        elif m_start == "04" and m_end == "06":
            return "Q2-" + yr_start[2:4]
        elif m_start == "07" and m_end == "09":
            return "Q3-" + yr_start[2:4]
        elif m_start == "10" and m_end == "12":
            return "Q4-" + yr_start[2:4]
    else:
        return "{} - {}".format(x['Start Date'], x['End Date'])

df.loc[:, 'Period'] = df.loc[: , ['Start Date', 'End Date']].apply(lambda x: get_period_form_start_and_end(x), axis=1)
```

So first we define a function which handles what type of period it is and then we apply this function to the concerning columns in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You need flatten dictionary for all combination of periods with values of dict by list comprehension with [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

```
Period = dict({("2019-01","2019-12"):"Cal-19",
            ("2020-01","2020-12"):"Cal-20",
            ("2021-01","2021-12"):"Cal-21",
            ("2019-01","2019-03"):"Q1-19",
            ("2019-04","2019-06"):"Q2-19",
            ("2019-07","2019-09"):"Q3-19",
            ("2019-10","2019-12"):"Q4-19",
            ("2020-01","2020-03"):"Q1-20",
            ("2020-04","2020-06"):"Q2-20",
            ("2020-07","2020-09"):"Q3-20"})
```

---

```
d = {x:v for (k1,k2), v in Period.items() for x in pd.period_range(k1, k2, freq='M')}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Period': pd.period_range('2019-01', '2020-09', freq='M')})

#map by dictioanry d
df["Period"] = df["Start Period"].map(d)
print (df)
   Start Period Period
0       2019-01  Q1-19
1       2019-02  Q1-19
2       2019-03  Q1-19
3       2019-04  Q2-19
4       2019-05  Q2-19
5       2019-06  Q2-19
6       2019-07  Q3-19
7       2019-08  Q3-19
8       2019-09  Q3-19
9       2019-10  Q4-19
10      2019-11  Q4-19
11      2019-12  Q4-19
12      2020-01  Q1-20
13      2020-02  Q1-20
14      2020-03  Q1-20
15      2020-04  Q2-20
16      2020-05  Q2-20
17      2020-06  Q2-20
18      2020-07  Q3-20
19      2020-08  Q3-20
20      2020-09  Q3-20
```